# C++: va_list error generic thunk code fails for method

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

This is my class:

```
class ControlBoard : public ILCD
{
    virtual void print(const GFX_STRING &string, ...);

    // ...
```

This my interface:

```
class ILCD
{
    virtual void print(const GFX_STRING &string, ...) = 0;

    // ...
```

This is my method:

```
void ControlBoard::print(const GFX_STRING &string, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, string);
    // ...
    va_end(args);       
}
```

And this is the compilation error:

> error: generic thunk code fails for method 'virtual void ControlBoard::print(const GFX_STRING&, ...)' which uses '...'

If the method "print()" is not in my ILCD interface, the compilation is fine. But I need to add it, so I don't understand why this error appears ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: change `&string` to `*string`

Comment: @bruno.karklis : no impact!

Comment: Although the use of a reference type as the last named parameter is indeed invalid as pointed out, the problem here is something entirely different. This is just an example where parts of the compiler's code generation are not fully implemented for a particular platform. A quick search for that error message brings up explanations. The compiler brand (probably GCC), version, and platform would be relevant information in helping you get a usable workaround.

Answer (score -3):

A simple c code with va_list

```
int WriteLog ( const char *pszBuffer, ... )
{
    FILE *fp;
    int iRet = FAIL;
    va_list vaListArguments = NULL; 

    fp = _tfopen( LOGPATH, "a" );

    if( NULL == fp )
    {
        return FAIL;
    }

    if( NULL != pszBuffer )
    {
        va_start( vaListArguments, pszBuffer );

        if( NULL != vaListArguments )
        {
            iRet = _vftprintf(fp, pszBuffer, vaListArguments);

            if( 0 <= iRet )
            {
                _ftprintf( fp, " \n");
                fflush( fp );                
                iRet = SUCCESS;
            }
        }
        va_end(vaListArguments);
        fclose( fp );
    }

    return iRet;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but why my method can't build ??

Comment: Why `&string` is in `void ControlBoard::print(const GFX_STRING &string, ...)` and not `*string` ?

Comment: I tried with *string, and I have the same compilation error !

Comment: I modified my initial post. Thanks for your help